# Notification does not correctly work (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

My notification does not correctly work. When my app is open and I get notification -> I click and I go to activity what I need. But when my app is closed and get notification -> I click this notification -> go to home activity, not activity what I need.

For example I have `HomeActivity`, `NotificationActivity`. When my app is open and I have notification I go to `NotificationActivity` but when my app is closed and I click I go to `HomeActivity`(I don need go to this place).

```
count++;
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
                wl.acquire(15000);

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
                mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);

                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification); 
                mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon));
mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000});
                mBuilder.setTicker(name);
                mBuilder.setContentText(message);
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
                mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));

Intent i = new Intent(ctx, NotificationActivity.class); 
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                ctx,
                                count,
                                i,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


               mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
               NotificationManager myNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                       ctx.getSystemService(ctx.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                myNotificationManager.notify(count, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add click_action in notification object in server side where you push notification
like click_action = 'notification_activity'
your fcm send notification server side object like this

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "First Notification",
     "title": "Collapsing A",
     "click_action": "notification_activity"
 }
}
```

after this you have to add intent filter for Notification Activity in manufeast file

```
<activity android:name=".NotificationActivity"
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="notification_activity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

After this your firebase messaging service change like below

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),action);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String body, String title, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
//here your notification builder code...
    }
}
```